Is there any hindu sect that rejects both caste and varna system?
I was surprised to see that even Advaita Vedanta has the system, which is non-dualistic so it does not really add up.
Is there any sect that doesn't have it? Preferably a non-dual school of thought.


Lingayatism founded by Basavana in 12th century in Karnataka rejects caste system and Varna system. It is based on the Vachanas (not based on canonical scriptures like Vedas, Agamas etc) and even rejects Karma.
Kashmir Shaivism also called as Trika Shaivism  which is based on Bhairava Agamas rejects caste and Varna system since it is not based on Vedas. Younus Rashid, a popular journalist in his work "Kashmiri Shaivism: A Historical Overview" writes


Kashmiri Shaivism accepts no restrictions based on caste, creed, sex, etc. Every curious and devout aspirant can have access to it
both theoretically and practically. It gives more importance to
practice than to bookish knowledge and logical discussions.

